# Should an answer that primarily consists of an image that's no longer available be flagged?

Tags: support, flags

On Stack Overflow I have come across this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10915/best-way-to-model-many-to-one-relationships-in-nhibernate-when-dealing-with-a-le)

but 2 of the 10 answers have this
[image: screen shot showing Flickr "missing image"]

The links are [1 st](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11157/1051198) and [2nd link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11125/1051198)

Should these answers be flagged? (they may have been useful)

Comment: Yes, stuff like that should be flagged. They were also duplicate answers from the same user. I left comments and deleted them for now.